# No package php5-gmp available

Tags: php, centos, gmp

Alright, to use Blocktrail's API, I'm trying to install the *gmp* package of php using this command :-

```
yum install php5-gmp
```

This results to :-

```
[root@dsfx ~]# yum install php5-gmp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
No package php5-gmp available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've tried many solutions online, but all have failed.
What am I doing wrong here?

CentOS Version :- CentOS7.0-64 LAMP for VSI

PHP Version :- PHP 5.5.37

Answer (score 0):

The yum repositories on your system don't have the package to install. You'll need to find another repo which has the package and add it to your system or try downloading an rpm and installing it that way, such as from here:

https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php5-gmp(x86-32)

New repos can be saved in /etc/yum.repos.d/reponame.repo and should look like below:

```
[examplerepo]
name=Example Repository
baseurl=http://mirror.cisp.com/CentOS/6/os/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Comment: When I try your approach. I get this :-
`[root@dsfx bin]# rpm -ivh php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586.rpm
warning: php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libc.so.6 is needed by php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586
        libgmp.so.10 is needed by php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586
        php5 = 5.6.1 is needed by php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586
`

Comment: You need to resolve the dependencies it lists by installing/updating the identified packages.

Comment: `php5-gmp-5.6.1-69.1.i586.rpm` is an OpenSuse 13.x package. Not supposed to fit any version of CentOS. I guess you will have to rebuild the system php rpm packages, and add the configure option `--with-gmp` ... Please edit your post to include CentOS version, and the current php version.

Comment: @KnudLarsen 
Updated.